# How to access a component embedded inside ng-template?

Tags: angular

I have a container component which accepts templateRef and within that container component, I want to access a component(predefined) which is embedded inside template. Here I couldn't use ContentChild as it doesn't come via content.

```
//Container Component
@Component({
 selector: 'app-cnt',
 template: `<div>
    content goes here({{name}}):-
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-container>
    </div>`,
 styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class ContainerComponent  {
 @Input() name: string;
 @Input() template: TemplateRef<any>;
 //In this component i need to access Test component which comes in template 
}


//Container component usage
<app-cnt [template]="templ" name="{{ name }}"></app-cnt>
<ng-template #templ>
   <span style="color: green">Embed Test comonent</span>
   <app-test class="app-test"></app-test>
</ng-template>
```

Here is [stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-asbcw1)

Comment: this could be implemented by passing ngTemplateOutletContext containing `this` and then 'register' self inside of a parent, or passing 'register' callback from parent. That will work but doesn't look pretty at all. Isn't it possible to pass those templates as ng-content? if yes, problem becomes trivial

Comment: Thanks, @Andrei. Yes, this solution doesn't look clean but does its job. With ng-content reusability is an issue or user has to implement component instead of passing a simple template.

Comment: why? it is possible to use content like `<parent><span>sometext</span><child>childContent...</child></parent>`. with many elements in content, it seems to me everything will be ok with your case implemented with the help of ng-content